# How did Jerome pronounce the Latin language?

Tags: pronunciation, history, late-latin

Jerome (Eusebius Sophronius Hieronymus) lived between the 4<sup>th</sup> and 5<sup>th</sup> centuries. He translated the Bible into Latin as the Vulgate (Biblia Vulgata). How would he have pronounced the Latin language?

In particular, did he use the 10-vowel system (a, e, i, o, u, short and long each) or the 7-vowel system (a, i, u, open/closed e, open/closed o), or something in between? Did he merge ae/oe with e? Did he palatalize the c's before e's and i's?